# plotting 3D bar graph in matlab or excel

Tags: excel, matlab, file-io, plot, bar-chart

I need to plot a 3D bar graph in matlab or excel. I am going to use some dates in x-axis, time in y-axis and some amount on the z-axis. Each record in csv file looks like ...

18-Apr,                 21,   139.45

I am not sure how to do this right. can anyone help me please. I tried using pivort chart of excel. however, i could not manipulate the axis and use appropriate space between each tick.

thanks
kaisar

Answer (score 3):

Since the question is lacking details, let me illustrate with an example.

Consider the following code:

```
%# read file contents: date,time,value
fid = fopen('data.csv','rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %s %f', 'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);

%# correctly reshape the data, and extract x/y labels
num = 5;
d = reshape(C{1},num,[]); d = d(1,:);
t = reshape(C{2},num,[]); t = t(:,1);
Z = reshape(C{3},num,[]);

%# plot 3D bars
bar3(Z)
xlabel('date'), ylabel('time'), zlabel('value')
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',d, 'YTickLabel',t)
```

I ran on the following data file:

#### data.csv

```
18-Apr,00:00,0.85535
18-Apr,03:00,0.38287
18-Apr,06:00,0.084649
18-Apr,09:00,0.73387
18-Apr,12:00,0.33199
19-Apr,00:00,0.83975
19-Apr,03:00,0.37172
19-Apr,06:00,0.82822
19-Apr,09:00,0.17652
19-Apr,12:00,0.12952
20-Apr,00:00,0.87988
20-Apr,03:00,0.044079
20-Apr,06:00,0.68672
20-Apr,09:00,0.73377
20-Apr,12:00,0.43717
21-Apr,00:00,0.37984
21-Apr,03:00,0.97966
21-Apr,06:00,0.39899
21-Apr,09:00,0.44019
21-Apr,12:00,0.15681
22-Apr,00:00,0.32603
22-Apr,03:00,0.31406
22-Apr,06:00,0.8945
22-Apr,09:00,0.24702
22-Apr,12:00,0.31068
23-Apr,00:00,0.40887
23-Apr,03:00,0.70801
23-Apr,06:00,0.14364
23-Apr,09:00,0.87132
23-Apr,12:00,0.083156
24-Apr,00:00,0.46174
24-Apr,03:00,0.030389
24-Apr,06:00,0.7532
24-Apr,09:00,0.70004
24-Apr,12:00,0.21451
25-Apr,00:00,0.6799
25-Apr,03:00,0.55729
25-Apr,06:00,0.85068
25-Apr,09:00,0.55857
25-Apr,12:00,0.90177
26-Apr,00:00,0.41952
26-Apr,03:00,0.35813
26-Apr,06:00,0.48899
26-Apr,09:00,0.25596
26-Apr,12:00,0.92917
27-Apr,00:00,0.46676
27-Apr,03:00,0.25401
27-Apr,06:00,0.43122
27-Apr,09:00,0.70253
27-Apr,12:00,0.40233
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @@Amro, do you mind in illustrating how to change the range on the z-axis? for instance, to display the bars in the value range from [0.65,1], instead of from [0,1]. I tried to use `ZLim([zmin zmax]);` but the format of the 3D bar was completely loose.

Answer (score 0):

Use MATLAB's [CSV reading functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/csvread.html) (or write your own) and then use [`bar3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bar3.html) to display the data.